# R cannot be resolved error

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have the R.java file generated but I'm still getting "R cannot be resolved" all throughout my code. Can anyone help? It is not a problem with the R.java file and there are no problems in the xml files

Comment: here is the same problem. -  http://stackoverflow.com/q/885009/601868

Comment: I removed the [tag:r] tag, since this question is not about the R-project.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

- Make sure you import **your** R into the class (com.myactivity.R instead of android.R)
- Sometimes other errors can prevent the R from generating. Fix those first, then R will regenerate and the R problems will disappear.
- You could also try to do a clean of the project. In Eclipse this would be Project - Clean...

Comment: Well I have R.java, nothing is keeping that from generating. Also I've tried cleaning it and that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Delete the **R.Java**, it will be automatically recreated & the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all your XML files
2. Clean your project (Project > clean)

Answer (score 0):

might be a problem in one of the XML files - have a look into the console - often errors show up there and tell you where to look